# Увеличить поле text в форме html

Tags: html, css, form, input

Добрый день. Не могу понять почему не работает.
Стиль для `h1` специально добавил, чтобы просто проверить файлик "подключен" или нет. На `h1` стиль применяется.
При этом, если применять стиль не посредственно в `html`, то стиль работает.
Пробовал `input` или `input[type="text"]`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Формы</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/form.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="form1.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="test" name="test" placeholder="Введите текст" autofocus>
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
    </form>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>

<style>

input{
    width: 100%;
}

h1{
    color: green;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Одиночные теги следует закрывать `<meta />`;
2. `<style>...</style>` должен быть в `<head>...</head>`;
3. Проверьте путь к файлу `form.css`, возможно лишняя `/` в указании пути;

Приведенный код работает - заголовок зеленый и форма растягивается.

Comment: Первый пункт не обязателен!

Comment: У меня не работает.

Comment: <style>
h1{
 text-align: center;
}

input{
 width: 100%;
}

</style>

Comment: То что вверху, работает input, но не работает h1. Соответственно можно поменять местами в файле css, то получим наоборот h1 работает input нет

Answer (score 0):

`/form.css` - проверьте путь к файлу стилей формы.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Формы</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/form.css" type="text/css">
  
  <style>

    input{
        width: 100%;
    }

    h1{
        color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="form1.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="test" name="test" placeholder="Введите текст" autofocus>
        <input type="submit" value="Добавить">
    </form>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я собственно говоря зеленым цветом и проверил. То есть путь правильный